# UWP and SerialSample byte encoding error

Tags: c++, unicode, uwp, uart

I will start off by saying I'm new to UWP. I recently downloaded VS2017 and have begun work on creating an App based off of an older C++/CLI Winform project. The reason for this is to avoid device compatibility issues.

To the problem.

I've followed the SerialUART sample code availbe here https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/SerialUART/

And I have been able to connect and read data successfully from the arduino based device into the UWP App.  The problem I am having is that every so often the App throws a COMException error: "***No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page***"

It appears to be the same character (or set of characters) causing the issue. But when the arduino based device is connected to the arduino serial monitor, the data is printed out exactly as intended. Indeed, it is even saved to the SD card exactly as presented on the serial monitor.

I've used a ***'try'*** and ***'catch'*** block to prevent the app crashing, and printed the error out on the text block I'm using as a terminal window, but the error doesn't seem to clear. Every time new data is received, the error message is reprinted.
I have verified that it's only certain character(s) printed at test startup and test end that are causing the issue as I tried connecting to the arduino device halfway through a test and got test data streamed out no problem.

So, how do I clear this exception error? And why does the UWP app have trouble with certain characters when the aruino serial monitor does not?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i discovered what the problem was here. In my arduino application, I was sending out characters such as

> ²

and

> °

What happens in the arduino serial terminal, is, it prints out the alt-code symbol prior to the squared symbol or degree symbol being printed etc. It looks like a capital "A" with a hat, followed by the symbol being printed.

Im guessing this is a quirk of arduino serial terminal as to get round this, I actually was able to split the character code up (as they are two bytes wide) and print out the latter half of the byte only.

Problems arose in VS2017 UWP because it was only seeing half of the actual character code and throwing a wobbly. Taking out the 'fix' I came up with meant that it could interpret all serial data correctly. And VS is clever enough to know not to print out the alt-code symbol when displaying a squared symbol or degree symbol etc...